# Function is only working for certain subranges?

Tags: vba, excel

Main point of this function is to return the most common movie genre.

```
Function MoviesByGenre(genreRng As Range) As String
Dim genreList(1 To 4) As String
Dim current As Integer
current = 1
For i = 1 To genreRng.count
    Dim found As Integer
    found = 0
    For j = 1 To current
        If genreList(j) = genreRng.Cells(i) Then
            found = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If found = 0 Then
        genreList(current) = genreRng.Cells(i)
        current = current + 1
    End If
Next i

Dim genreCount(1 To 4) As Integer
For i = 1 To 4
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For j = 1 To genreRng.count
        If genreRng.Cells(j) = genreList(i) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next j
    genreCount(i) = count
Next i
MoviesByGenre = FindMax(genreCount, genreList)
End Function
```

Now my FindMax function looks like this:

```
Function FindMax(valueArray, nameArray) As String
Dim max As Double
max = valueArray(LBound(valueArray))
For i = LBound(valueArray) + 1 To UBound(valueArray)
    If valueArray(i) > valueArray(max) Then
       max = i
    End If
Next i
FindMax = nameArray(max)
End Function
```

FindMax appears to work well in other areas, but depending on the range I use for MoviesByGenre, it may or may not work. (sometimes it'll give me #VALUE!, other times it'll give me the actual most common movie genre, and i'm not sure why.) I'm using Excel 2016 for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim a As Variant
    a = Range("A1:A7").Value

    MsgBox FindMax(a)
End Sub

Function FindMax(valueArray) As String
    Dim max As Double
    Dim i As Long

    max = valueArray(LBound(valueArray), 1)
    For i = LBound(valueArray) + 1 To UBound(valueArray)
        If valueArray(i, 1) > max Then
            max = valueArray(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    FindMax = max
End Function
```

Comment: No, definition & parameters for the FindMax function were given.